# How to change position of the element on scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, window

I want to change the value of the property `top` **at the same time** I scroll.
I don't want to use `position: fixed`. I use `position: absolute`.

I would like to add `1px` to the `box` every time I scroll down.

I would like to remove `1px` to the `box` every time I scroll up.

How to do that ?

```
<div id="box" style="position: absolute">
   // content
</div>

$(document).bind('scroll', function(){ 
    $("#box").css("top", ..... ); 
});
```

Comment: So you don't want to use position: fixed what actually does what you need (assuming you want the box to stay at the same position no matter how you scroll), but you want to over-complicate things by using javascript to measure your scroll distance and modify your 'top' value accordingly?.. I have no clue why you want to make your stuff unnecessarily difficult..

Comment: Did you try to catch onscroll ? just save the position, and compare to new position.

Comment: @julesanchez How you do that ?

Comment: @steffi : all is on answers
1. add listener to scroll
2. Get position with scrollTop
3. Compare to previous value of scroll (if variable not null)
4. Save new position in the global variable

Comment: @doniyor Yeah I know. Don't worry. I just wait if another answer comes up. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this,

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  change_box_css();
});

function change_box_css(){
 //FF
 $('#box').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
 if(e.detail > 0) {
     //scroll down -> set css top
 }else {
     //scroll up   -> set css top
 }

 });

  //IE, Opera, Safari
 $('#box').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
 if(e.wheelDelta < 0) {
     //scroll down -> set css top

 }else {
     //scroll up -> set css top

 }

 });

 }
```

now you should set your css top according to your wish

Comment: Okay, but how to tell the difference between scroll up and scroll down here ?

Comment: That's a really heavy method for the browser :( _"It's a very, very, bad idea to attach handlers to the window scroll event."_ John Resig. Look at the **Best Practice** paragraph : http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: you are right.. but it depends on what and how much the attached handler does.. just setting css is not that big issue..

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#box").on('scroll', function(){

          $(this).css('top',$(document).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Although I agree that you should use `position: fixed`, unless you are trying to make a div 'follow' a user when he/she scrolls the page, like a sidebar or something.